# Azure - Virtual Network Gateway Limited IP Addresses - Solution Needed

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn, azure-nsg

Hoping someone here can help me find a solution to an issue we are having with a Virtual Network Gateway in Azure. I come from the development side so hoping there are some network gurus out there...

We have a VNG that has a dedicated site to site connection with a 3rd party. We need to access resources in their network but they only accept traffic coming from a very limited range of IP addresses .16/28. With azure reserving some of those and us having a few devices (virtual machines) already using up a couple more, we only have 1 address remaining. Problem is, I have 4 more employees that will need to access those resources so I can't put 4 more VMs on the 1 ip address remaining.

I am hoping for a solution along the lines of employees VPN to x device, then all traffic is routed to VNG over remaining IP? Or employees VPN to VNG and all use last remaining IP?

Like I said, I am dev guy so probably missing a blatantly obvious solution.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want Virtual Network NAT, a fully managed and highly resilient Network Address Translation (NAT) service. VNet NAT simplifies outbound Internet connectivity for virtual networks. When configured on a subnet, all outbound connectivity uses the VNet NAT's static public IP addresses.

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/nat-overview) provides an overview of NAT (Network Address Translation) support in Azure VPN Gateway. NAT defines the mechanisms to translate one IP address to another in an IP packet. There are multiple scenarios for NAT:

- Connect multiple networks with overlapping IP addresses
- Connect from
  networks with private IP addresses (RFC1918) to the Internet
  (Internet breakout)
- Connect IPv6 networks to IPv4 networks (NAT64)

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ken - we will certainly look into it. We have been told everything from "get more address space" to use a squid proxy. This is definitely helpful! Will update if we do go with this solution.

Comment: I was just furiously googling for a similar scenario. @ken-w-msft - Could this be used to get static outbound IPs for all VPN gateway connected clients? I'd like to use these IPs in Azure Storage firewalls e.g.: SQL dbs